# angular leaflet marker change property with function

Tags: angularjs, properties, leaflet, marker

I would like to change some leaflet marker properties by clicking a link outside the map, but it doesn't work.

Check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ls59qLLa/2/

js:

```
var app = angular.module('demoapp',['leaflet-directive']);

app.controller('DemoController', [ '$scope', 'leafletData', function($scope, leafletData) {

var local_icons = {
            defaultIcon: {},
            gmapicon: {
                iconUrl: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/capital_big.png',
                iconSize:     [25, 25],
                iconAnchor:   [12, 12], 
                popupAnchor:  [0, 0] 
            }
        }


angular.extend($scope, {
    markers: {
                m1: {
                    lat: 41.85,
                    lng: -87.65,
                    clickable: false,
                    message: "I'm a static marker",
                    icon: local_icons.gmapicon
                }
            }
});

$scope.makeIconClickable = function(){
    alert('function called');
    var whichmarker = 'm1';
    $scope.markers[whichmarker].clickable = true;


}


}]);
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="DemoController">
    <leaflet markers="markers"></leaflet>
     <a href="#" ng-click=makeIconClickable()>Make Icon Clickable</a>    
   </body>
```

Comment: interesting - you can toggle `draggable` with your method, but not `clickable`.

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet directive has separate `$watch` for every marker (and path) on the map. When you change one of the marker property, this `$watch` is fired and it checks if some of properties has changed. Apparently it does not look for the `clickable` property, but it looks for `message` property. So in your function you could set message of the marker and everything binds properly:

```
$scope.makeIconClickable = function(){
    var whichmarker = 'm1';
    $scope.markers[whichmarker].clickable = true;
    $scope.markers[whichmarker].message = "I'm a static marker";
}
```

If you need to set message on marker initialization phase, you can use some temporary property:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    markers: {
        m1: {
            lat: 41.85,
            lng: -87.65,
            icon: local_icons.gmapicon,
            tmpmessage: 'I am a static marker'
        }
    }
});
```

And then:

```
$scope.makeIconClickable = function(){
    var whichmarker = 'm1';
    $scope.markers[whichmarker].clickable = true;
    $scope.markers[whichmarker].message =  $scope.markers[whichmarker].tmpmessage;   
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3zgL8m4u/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I sometimes need the map to fire an onClick Event even if the user clicked the Marker. The answer provided by "Agnieszka Świecznik" is a quick and easy workaround if all you need is no Popup to be shown. It does not solve my problem, since it only removes the Popup, but no onClick Event on the map is fired.

To solve this i found this official Thread which seems to have been opened by the OP: https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/issues/676

Here a link to a modified JSFiddle is Provided: http://jsfiddle.net/nmccready/gbd1aydL/

The user who provided this fix included the following codeblock in the "angular-leaflet-directive.js" which can be found in the jsfiddle under "external resources":

```
var _destroy = function(markerModels, oldMarkerModels, lMarkers, map, layers){
    // Delete markers from the array
    var hasLogged = false,
      modelIsDiff = false;
    var doCheckOldModel =  isDefined(oldMarkerModels);
    for (var name in lMarkers) {
        if(!hasLogged) {
            $log.debug(errorHeader + "[markers] destroy: ");
            hasLogged = true;
        }

        if(doCheckOldModel){
          //might want to make the option (in watch options) to disable deep checking
          //ie the options to only check !== (reference check) instead of angular.equals (slow)
          modelIsDiff = !angular.equals(markerModels[name],oldMarkerModels[name]);
        }
        if (!isDefined(markerModels) ||
            !Object.keys(markerModels).length ||
            !isDefined(markerModels[name]) ||
            !Object.keys(markerModels[name]).length ||
            modelIsDiff) {
            deleteMarker(lMarkers[name], map, layers);
            delete lMarkers[name];
        }
    }
};
```

Note that this seems to be an older Version, as noted in the file itself: "angular-leaflet-directive 0.7.11 2015-04-08". When included in my AngularJS Project this allowed me to change the clickable property of the marker by just modifiyng the corresponding boolean in my "$scope.markers"-equivalent.